# How to cite submitted paper?

Tags: bibtex

Given this reference:

> J. Simmonds, S. Ben-David, and M. Chechik. Optimizing Computation of
>   Recovery Plans for BPEL Applications,
>   2010. Submitted.

how can the "submitted" be added using BibTeX?

Comment: Use the `note` field in the bib-entry.